# Holomorphic functions on the product of open sets.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Is it true that 
$$
\mathcal H(\mathrm U \times \mathrm V) \simeq \mathcal H(\mathrm U) \widehat{\otimes} \mathcal H(\mathrm V)
$$

for open two open affine sets $\mathrm U$ and $\mathrm V$?

Edit: I am particulary interested in the case $\mathrm U = \mathrm V = \mathbb C^\times$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\widehat{\otimes}$"?

Comment: Completed tensor product. As all the spaces are nuclear here, you can take the one you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for arbitrary domains $U,V\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, see corollary 4.15 in *The Homology of Banach and Topological Algebras by A. Ya. Helemskii.*

Comment: Corollary 4.15 says that it is true, at least if $\mathrm U$ or $\mathrm V$ is simply connected. What happens when $\mathrm U = \mathrm V = \mathbb C^\ast$?

Comment: Below there is a note it is true for all domains